# I have JSON Object, with this object i need to find the ID Number of "xxxEmployeeCategory "T" and list the list in an Array

Tags: jquery, json

This is JSON Object that I get as response . This contains items, category, ID, firstname etc

```
    {
        "items": [{
        "xxxEmployeeCategory": "T",
        "idNumber": 661153498,
        "firstName": "Steven",
        "lastName": "Babineau",
        "department": "ATHLETICS",
        "title": "Hd Mn Socc Cch/Life Skill",
        "email": "sbabineau@xxxme.edu",
        "officeLocation": "",
        "phoneNumber": "1-617-399-8777"
    },   {
        "xxxEmployeeCategory": "S",
        "idNumber": 12466,
        "firstName": "Matthew",
        .......
        .......
    }]
}
```

The problem is that I am unable to reach to ID of a xxxEmployeeCategory through jQuery.

Comment: please for the love of Code! Don't ever Post like this

Comment: from where do you get this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through using $.each() or for (),push into an array

```
var idList=[];
$.each(items,function(index,item){

    if(item.xxxEmployeeCategory == "T"){
        var id=item.idNumber;
        idList.push(id);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume you've stored the parsed response in a variable `data`. i.e:

```
var data = {
    "items": [{
      "xxxEmployeeCategory": "T",
      "idNumber": 661153498,
      // other properties
    },{
      "xxxEmployeeCategory": "S",
      "idNumber": 12466,
      // other properties
    }]
};
```

You have multiple objects having `xxxEmployeeCategory` in the `items` array.

For accessing specific property, you should first access the object using it's index in `items` array

```
var obj = data.items[0]; // points to the first object
```

You can then access the specific property like `obj.xxxEmployeeCategory` using the  `.` operator like

```
var xxxEmployeeCategory= data.items[0].xxxEmployeeCategory;
```

You can access the property of each object by looping through the array.

---

If you want to get the `xxxEmployeeCategory` of all objects, you can use the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) method as follows:

```
var employeeCategoryList = $.map(data.items,function(obj){
  return obj.xxxEmployeeCategory;
});
```

Which will return an array containing the `xxxEmployeeCategory` property values of all items

Answer (score 0):

Since .each() and etc approach have been discussed let me put in a different way to achieve this,

```
for(var i=0;i<items[i].length; i++) {
   if(items[i].xxxEmployeeCategory=='T') {
      alert(items[i].idNumber);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey all thanks for all your response. Finally i have achieved the same by using json linq

```
var strIDsArray = $.Enumerable.From(jsonData.items).Where(function(x) {
 return x.xxxEmployeeCategory == "T"
 }).Select(function(x) {
 return x.idNumber
 }).ToArray();

 console.log(strIDsArray);
```